# Use substitution variables Oracle SQL Expert Topic

Tags: oracle, variables, certificate, substitution, oracle12c

I'm currently preparing for Oracle SQl expert exam [It's page](https://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=5001&get_params=p_exam_id:1Z0-047).
I found topic named "Use substitution variables". This looks like SQlStarPlus topic (using something like WHERE id = '&param' for better using in cmd), but there in the official page there is nothing about SQLStarPlus, only SQL and PL/SQL.
Maybe I'm wrong and they mean some other substitution variables?

Can you please tell me: what is substitution variables in Oracle 12c SQL not SQL*Plus?

Comment: SQL*Plus?  It IS sqlplus.  There is no difference.

Comment: Yes, I know, I mean there are only 2 options:
1) Oracle community included sqlplus topic and haven't added it in "Exam product" section;
2) There are other substitution variables, not in sqlplus.
And I want to find out which option is true :(

Comment: Are you attempting to take the certification exam at this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitution variables **are** an SQL*Plus concept, they don't exist in SQL or PL/SQL. SQL*Plus has its own scripting language, distinct from SQL and PL/SQL; for example `describe <table_name>` and `column <column_name> format a30` only exist in SQL*Plus, not in SQL or PL/SQL.

The exam clearly requires some knowledge of SQL*Plus, even if it is not in the exam title. The title is only a broad indication of what an exam covers; the long list of topics the exam covers is the "actual law," not the exam title.